# what does material-ui theme.palette.primary.light do?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

what does material-ui theme.palette.primary.light do? For example theme.palette.primary.dark represents the color of hover state for a primary button and main is for the normal color of the button. But what is light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused a bit. The palette is different from the theme [material-ui.com/customization/color](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/).

In material design it is used to have three shades of a color (light, main and dark) to completely cover any possible usage.
Also in some cases hover and active button states are styled differently.
Primary, doesn't necessarily mean button. It can be your site brand color, and having a light version of it could make sense as a background in a card/ component/page/et al.